# angularfire Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $firebaseStorageProvider <- $firebaseStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I use "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.1/firebase.js"

and "https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"

My app.js

```
 angular
      .module('angularfireApp', [
        'firebase',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch'
      ])
```

my controller.js

```
angular.module('angularfireApp')
  .controller('ProductsCtrl', function (Auth, $scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $firebaseStorage) {
```

Any idea of what the problem is, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the latest version ([2.3.0](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/releases/tag/v2.3.0) as of now) of `angularfire` because they have recently added a service to wrap the functions of `$firebaseStorage`. Please check the following release notes:

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/releases

Therefore, change your `angularfire` reference to the following:

https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js

You should be fine after that :)

PS - [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sahansera/p8qye164/)

Comment: Gald to hear that. Please mark it as the accepted answer if it works for you, so others can easily find it too :)